How is sectional curvature determined by values on 2-planes.
I'm a beginner on Riemannian geometry so I hope this question does make some sense.
The sectional curvature is $K(X,Y)=\frac{R(X,Y,Y,X)}{\langle X,X\rangle\langle Y,Y\rangle-\langle X,Y\rangle^2}$, it depends only on the plane spaned by $X,Y$. But how many values of $K$ on 2-planes do I need to completely determine the whole $K$? For example, in dimension 3, is knowing values of $K(E_1,E_2),K(E_1,E_3),K(E_2,E_3)$ for some orthonormal frames $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ enough to determine $K$? For example if these three equals some constant, then can we say the manifold has constant sectional curvature(or is there a counter-example)?
I want to explain why this confuses me. $K$ is not a tensor, it is actually a function on unit tangent bundle, at each point it can be defined on a sphere. But I cannot understand how this function looks like, if we look at a plane $X^iE_i\wedge Y^iE_i$, $K(X,Y)=\frac{X^iY^jY^kX^l}{|X\wedge Y|}R(E_i,E_j,E_k,E_l)$, there are thus ${\binom{n}{2}}+\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}$ datas to determine $K$(I'm not sure if they are independent). So in dimension 3 there should be an example, a manifold does not have constant curvature but do have sectional curvature $K(E_1,E_2)=K(E_1,E_3)=K(E_2,E_3)=c$? Besides, is knowing $K$ on 6 random planes uniquely determines $K$?

Yes to both your questions. Use multilinearity of $R$.

@TedShifrin, the space of $3$-dimensional curvature tensors is 6-dimensional. So I don't think the sectional curvatures listed is enough. However, if you assume that $(E_1,E_2,E_3)$ diagonalizes the Ricci tensor, then three sectional curvatures listed do uniquely determine the curvature tensor.

Whoops @Deane. Of course you're correct. I was being dopey and forgot about the "bad" cross-terms. Some things fade away in retirement. :P

@TedShifrin, I'm pretty sure I make more errors than you. Yours are quite rare.

@EricLey, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_of_Riemannian_manifolds#Sectional_curvature
